# package.json : who is the target of "main:umd": "dist/umd/bundl.js" ? which tool can use it? is it a standard name for umd?

Tags: npm, webpack, rollup, popperjs

package json of [popper.js](https://github.com/popperjs/popper-core)  contains

```
"main:umd": "dist/umd/popper.js"
```

I am interesting to understand is this a standard way to instruct modern bundlers|tools (which of them?) or just the popper specific?

Is it a standard naming? Can I use "main:esm" with those tools?

I can't find anything about `"main:umd"` in google.